# Finding the directional derivative.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

We need to find the directional derivative of the function , $f(x,y) = x^{2}+y^{2}+xy$ at $P(1,-1)$ in the direction towards origin.

The direction towards origin form the point $(1,-1)$ is represented by a unit vector $u$ ,

Is it correct to take $u=\dfrac{-i-j}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The direction towards the origin $O$ from $P$ is represented by the vector
$$\mathbf u = O - P = (-1, 1).$$

The unit vector will then be
$$\mathbf{\hat u} = \frac{\mathbf u}{\|\mathbf u\|} = \left(-\frac1{\sqrt{2}}, \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{-\mathbf{\hat\imath} + \mathbf{\hat\jmath}}{\sqrt 2}.$$

We then have
$$\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm d{\mathbf{\hat u}}} = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{\hat u}.$$